# How can I save an insect-damaged Gardenia?

Tags: watering, pest-control, insects, roots, technique

It is a Gardenia. Insects infested the soil so I added diatomaceous earth to it, but maybe I was too late. The plant continued dying, so I pulled it out and set it in a bath filled with water to which I added Bayer brand insecticide. But as you can see, the plant continues to die.

How can I save it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You *bathed the bare roots in insecticide*? Seriously?

Comment: Well, wouldn't that have been same as watering with insecticide?

Comment: Oh sweetie...don't take it personally.  We've all done dumb things, that is how us professionals learn!  No...bathing roots in chemicals was probably a death sentence.  What insect were you thinking of controlling when you chose the insecticide?  You have found a superb site to help you be successful the next time! Please don't give up.  This guy would take a miracle to save.  Sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

With that level of root hair damage, your chances of life for the Gardenia (a plant rather root sensitive) are rather slim. You probably won't be able to salvage this one. You could try potting it up in a moist acidic mix (not a potting soil) and keeping it damp in a cool to warmish humid area, in low light. And don't fertilize. There's a chance it can come around, but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any viable shoots can I suggest you take some cuttings, pot them up, so if this one dies (it's looking likely I'm afraid) you will eventually have your gardenia back.